# use anullsrc in ffmpeg command

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have ffmpeg command that i want to add **anullsrc** filter to it

I tried to add the command in different places there but there is always a problem. the command is taking 2 movies and merging them to one movie side by side. the audio is the 2 movies together.

This is the command:

ffmpeg -i loop2.mp4 -i loop1.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=black[a];[1:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=black[b];nullsrc=size=640x480[base];[a]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x480[left];[b]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x480[right];[base][left]overlay=shortest=1[tmp1];[tmp1][right] overlay=320:0[video];[video]overlay=5:5[videoandlogo];[0:a]apad [apa];[apa][1:a]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|FL

In the command i have the **nullsrc** for the video and i want to add also the **anullsrc** for the audio. 
Can some one help? Thanks.

I have a problem when doing this command with the right file (always the right, even if i switched the files), the audio is not synced with the video and i think its because i didn't use the anullsrc (maybe i am wrong). it happens only on files that i concat them - took one video, and concat it a few times to itself with a different command - loop, and created a new file. the looped video is synced, only the merge is destroying the audio sync (on regular files without loop the sync is good after the merge). 
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want the anullsrc?

Comment: because i think that when i am using nullsrc without anullsrc it only returns unprocessed video frames and unprocessed audio frames which may causing the video audio get out of sync. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use '-f lavfi -t duration -i anullsrc' as an input source